# Web to lead assignment to User with least open lead count

Tags: map, queue, web2lead, aggregateresult, lead-assignment

I have created a Map 'userIdWithOpenLeadCountMap' and grouped by OpenLeadCount in the ASC order. Then I am getting the first Key from the Map (UserID:005E0000003X2MH) and assigning a new lead to this User.  So far so good ! At this point, UserId 005E0000003X2MH LeadCount becomes 4.

| UserId | OpenLeadCount |
| --- | --- |
| 005E0000003X2MH | 3 |
| 005E0000003Y7JX | 3 |
| 005E0000003Z2BL | 8 |
| 005E0000003A2MX | 8 |
| 005E0000003D2VS | 10 |

**My Problem:**

Before a new lead gets created in Salesforce, If the User '005E0000003X2MH'  closes a lead, the OpenLeadCount again goes to 3. When this new lead is created, I want to ensure it is assigned to UserId '005E0000003Y7JX'  However I am lost what logic I could apply. Can some one please point me in the correct direction.

Basically, I am trying to assign the lead to the user with minimum open leads. However if two users have equal openleadcount, I want to implement RoundRobin at this point.

Note: I looked in to OmniChannel, and came to the conclusion that it won't work for my Use Case.

Comment: I think you might need a tie breaker key which would be the datetime of last closed lead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created logic based on  last closed lead as suggested by @cropredy